# Lambdas accessing final fields of the enclosing class before initialisation

Tags: lambda, java-8, final

I found behaviour which I cannot explain when accessing a final field of a class from an enclosed lambda expression. This is the example program:

```
public class FinalAccessTest {

  // Some fields
  private int nonfinalfield=4;
  private final int directfinalfield=5;
  private final int constructorfinalfield;

  // element method for the final field with delayed assignment
  private int getConstructorFinalField() { return constructorfinalfield; }

  // Some lambda expressions accessing the fields from above
  private final Supplier<Integer> nonfinalsupp=()->nonfinalfield;  // OK
  private final Supplier<Integer> directfinalsupp=()->directfinalfield;  // OK
  private final Supplier<Integer> constructorfinalsuppA=
    ()->this.constructorfinalfield;  // OK
  private final Supplier<Integer> constructorfinalsuppB=
    ()->getConstructorFinalField();   // OK

  // This one does not compile: The blank final field
  //   constructorfinalfield may not have been initialized
  //private Supplier<Integer> constructorfinalsuppC=()->constructorfinalfield;

  public FinalAccessTest() {
    System.out.println(constructorfinalsuppA.get()); // prints "0"
    System.out.println(constructorfinalsuppB.get()); // prints "0"

    // Does not compile: "may not have been initialized"
    //System.out.println(constructorfinalfield);

    constructorfinalfield=6;
    System.out.println(constructorfinalsuppA.get()); // prints "6"
    System.out.println(constructorfinalsuppB.get()); // prints "6"
    System.out.println(constructorfinalfield); // Compiles and prints "6"

    // now access to a non-final field
    System.out.println(nonfinalsupp.get()); // prints "4"
    nonfinalfield=17;
    System.out.println(nonfinalsupp.get()); // prints "17"

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) { new FinalAccessTest(); }

}
```

Obviously it is possible to access a final field of a class which is initialized within the constructor before its actual initialisation in a lambda expression by

- either referring to the field by `this.<field>`
- or using an element method `get<Field>()`.

On the other hand, it seems generally not possible to access such **final** fields by simply referencing `<field>` in the lambda expression. And I thought, `this` in a lambda always referencing the enclosing class so that `<field>` and `this.<field>` are effectively the same.

To make confusion complete, this all only applies to **final** fields which are **initialized in the constructor**. For non-final fields or final fields which are initialized in the declaration, access by `<field>` is perfectly possible and uses the value of the field at lambda invocation time.

What is going on here? Is this a general shortcoming of the lambda expression definition/engine, a bug in specific Java versions (8u66) or just a feature? I'm a bit puzzled. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: You are ignoring the order of initialization. Accessing a `final` field at a point where it is already initialized, is always valid. And fields with an initializer are initialized in declaration order *before* the constructors body. Then, the only remaining question is why prepending `this.` or using a method weakens the rules, but that’s [because the specification says so](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3)…

Comment: I understand the initialisation order. However, it is inconsistent to allow accessing `this.constructorfinalfield` but not `constructorfinalfield`, regardless of its initialisation. Also, `getConstructorFinalField()` can also only be called directly _after_ the field has been initialized. All these inconsistencies only appear in functional expressions. And that's what I find weird.

Comment: This has nothing to do with functional expressions. I already provided the link to the relevant part of the specification, which defines exactly that behavior, in terms of ordinary expressions accessing the fields. It’s not intuitive that `final int i=j, j=42;` is illegal, but `final int i=this.j, j=42;` is not, but that’s how it is specified. You may call it inconsistent, but that’s not the question. You asked whether it is a bug and the answer is, no, this is specified behavior.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. My impression is that these - well - not totally intuitive specifications become more visible with the raise of functional programming due to principle of immutability ("final") and lambdy expressions. After all, it feels a bit like the dim outskirts of Java city...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object initializers (i.e. declarations of the form field = value in your class) run **before** the constructor in order of appearance. Thus, the first declarations all access fields which have already been initialized at that time, while the fields created in the constructor will only be initialized **after** the respective object initializer.

Comment: I know all this. But the access permissions to those `final` fields from lambdas seem inconsistent and counterintuitive to me. Especially as the central promise of a `final` field - it does never change - is broken here.

Answer (score 0):

`this.constructorFinalField` is an error in Eclipse Photon.  So less inconsistency.